Godot 4.3 - Problem with 2D Object Movement: Pet following player and random movement behavior
I'm working on this pet system. It will move in the character's direction and when entering "their field", it will make random movements around it. The problem is that the pet's object becomes "trembling", as objects do when colliding with others. What can I do?
My code
    extends Node2D

var is_active = false
var move_speed = 90.0
var follow_distance = 90.0
var random_move_timer = 0.0
var random_direction = Vector2()
var random_move_interval = 1.0 

var player = null

func random_move(delta):
    random_move_timer += delta
    if random_move_timer >= random_move_interval:
        random_move_timer = 0.0
        random_direction = Vector2(randf_range(-1, 1), randf_range(-1, 1)).normalized()
    global_position += random_direction * move_speed * delta

func move_towards_player(delta):
    if player:
        var direction = player.global_position - global_position
        var distance = direction.length()
        if distance > 0:
            direction = direction.normalized()
        var speed_factor = clamp(distance / 100.0, 1.0, 3.0)
        if distance > 0.5:
            global_position += direction * move_speed * speed_factor * delta  

func toggle_active(player_node):
    is_active = !is_active
    if is_active:
        player = player_node
        show()
    else:
        player = null
        hide()

func update_depth():
    if player:
        if global_position.y < player.global_position.y:
            z_index = -1
        else:
            z_index = 1

func _process(delta):
    if is_active and player:
        var distance = global_position.distance_to(player.global_position)
        if distance > follow_distance:
            move_towards_player(delta)
        else:
            random_move(delta) 
        update_depth()

